# How to regenerate Windows boot files without being able to boot into it

Tags: linux, windows, boot, multi-boot, efi

So I have an EFI dual boot system with Windows and Arch, and because of some grub tomfoolery I ended up completely wiping the EFI partition and installing systemd-boot. But now I don't have any way to boot into Windows as those EFI entries are gone.
So I'm wondering how I can regenerate those files from a live usb. Can I get a Windows usb, use cmd from it and run bcdboot ? Or is there a simpler solution ? I don't want to remove my linux entries. Thanks

Comment: You may be able to try a Windows Startup Repair from the Windows ISO but I do not know if that will regenerate the UEFI partition.

Comment: Can you still boot into Linux? If the answer is Yes, see [this link](https://linuxconfig.org/booting-a-ms-windows-os-using-grub). If not, try to fix your boot with [Rescatux & Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/).

Comment: As I said, I'm now using systemd-boot.

Answer (score 2):

Get a Windows USB stick, use Cmd from it, then run bcdboot.

By default, it will place the newly created "Windows" boot entry first in the EFI `BootOrder`. Use `/addlast` if you don't want that.